# Where is cmake located when downloaded from visual studio 2022

Tags: cmake

Where is cmake located when downloading it from visual studio 2022 as I wanted to add it in environmental variables

Comment: It's always possible to use `message("cmake exe location: ${CMAKE_COMMAND}")` to a cmake file. Assuming VS does show you the output of the cmake configuration, this should print the absolute path of the cmake executable...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Launch the Native Tools Command Prompt (accessible via the Start Menu). From here you can run:

```
> where cmake
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe
```

to determine the location. I expect that for VS2022 the path will be very similar.

---

***However***, the version of CMake distributed with Visual Studio has patches from Microsoft. You should either install upstream CMake for use outside of the Native Tools Command Prompt, or just *use the Native Tools Command Prompt*.

Comment: 2022....   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe